# Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ be a $s$-permutable subgroup of $G$. if index $|G:H|=p$. then $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$H$ is called $s$-permutable in $G$ if it permutes with every Sylow subgroup of $G$.

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ be a $s$-permutable subgroup of $G$. if index $|G:H|=p$, where $p$ is an odd prime divisor of $|G|$, (Not necessarily the smallest prime). then $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$.

Any help/answer/hint will be appreciated so much; thank you all..

Comment: Hint: First show that $H$ contains all $q$-Sylow subgroups for $q\neq p$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I show   that $H$ contains all $q$-Sylow subgroups for $q \neq p$.can you explain more. thanks

Comment: The subgroup generated by those Sylow subgroups is normal with index a power of $p$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft can you give me the reference?

Comment: This will be in pretty much any book on group theory that goes just a bit beyond the basics. It is also not that hard to show.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft can you help me?

Comment: Not sure what you need help with. I assumed that you were familiar with some of the basic things involved here since you are studying $s$-permutable subgroups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft i got it. thanks